# OnClick restartActivity?

Tags: android, button, android-activity, onclick, restart

How can I restart An Activity on click?

For exemple: I have got in my `AndroidManifest.xml` 2 activities the activity A and B and they start when application starts...

But what I want is when I click in a button that is on Activity A it must restart activity B.

Comment: what's the purpose of the restart? You can call invalidate()/postInvalidate() on Activity to make it re-draw itself, calling internally onDraw().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you are in activity A, and proceeding to activity B, then your activity B automatically starts/re-starts

Answer (score 1):

Why do you need to start both Activities on starting your app? When you say "restart", do you actually need to stop Activity B and start Activity B again? Or do you just want to show it? To start an Activity from another Activity, you could call something like this:

```
startActivity(new (Intent(this, ActivityB.class)));
```

The Android [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#StartingActivities) gives plenty of detail. However, I think you should consider why you are starting two activities at once, and whether you might want to use a `Service` instead (not knowing any details of your app, I can't say).

Answer (score 0):

```
Intent intent = new Intent(CurrentActivity.this, ActivityToLaunch.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

call above piece of code on `onClick` of view method.